# Style span inside option - Select menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just want to style a span tag that inside in select menu option. Just like this

[image]

I tried to write and inline css but, it didn't work.

```
<select>
<option selected>Pick Up Time</option>
<option value="1">09.00-100 <span style="background-color: blue;">(Unavailable)</span></option>
<select>
```

Then I tried with selectpicker [plugin](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/), It seems it doesn't have option to do that. Any alternative way to do this? or jquery solution?

Comment: In my experience it's really hard to style a native select, what I have done in the past is to create a custom dropdown. It depends on your application needs. Looking at the plugin that you provide, you might want to check out a combination between custom-content and disabled options.

Comment: at the end of this page there is a custom made datalist , you can do the same for a select item [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)